# Is there a low-level alternative to Animate Objects?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, dnd-adventurers-league

I am playing a lvl-4 halfling druid with a background as a woodworker craftsman. I would like to be able to carve small wooden creatures, and then animate them. The 5th-level spell Animate Objects seems to be a bit of overkill for this application; is there a more appropriate alternative?

We are playing AL, and the DM is quite a stickler for rules, but we can use PHB plus 1 other hardcover 5e.

This question is being driven more by a character-building motive of trying to connect the character's previous life as a wood carver to his current life as a spell casting adventurer. There is no specific (e.g., combat-related) goal.

I just thought it would be cool to have some wooden creatures to play with that can:

- be sent on errands
- fake out monsters/guards
- engage in combat distraction

Comment: What do you want the small wooden creatures to be able to do?

Comment: Related: [How would you bring inanimate object to life as allies?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/115448/33707)

Comment: How are you planning on getting access to *animate objects* as a druid?

Comment: I don't have access to my books at the moment, but IIRC there's a pet-summoning subclass for the Druid in XGtE that might fit this character.

Answer (score 10):

## [Tiny Servant](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/tiny-servant)

In *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, pp. 168-169, there is a spell called *tiny servant* that seems to be what you're looking for. It's a 3rd level spell, so you would have the necessarily spell slots next level (when you reach 5th level), but it's only on the wizard's spell list, not the druid's.

If there's a way that you or your DM can enable your druid to have access to this spell, it would enable you to animate one object rather than many objects like *animate objects* does.

Comment: Are there by-the-book rules for accessing other classes spells? We are playing AL, and the DM is quite a stickler for rules, but we can use PHB +1 other hardcover 5e.

Comment: @Jeremy: The way suggested above would not work according to AL rules. I would also recommend you add that info into your question! (along with the clarifications asked in the comments)

Comment: OP has updated what they want their carvings to do, you may want to adjust your answer.

Answer (score 9):

### Consider a slight reflavoring of *[Conjure Animals](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/conjure-animals)*.

The 3rd level Druid spell *Conjure Animals* states that:

> You summon fey spirits that take the form of beasts and appear in
>   unoccupied spaces that you can see within range.

It would be nearly equivalent, mechanically, if your character first tossed out his wooden animal statues to the desired locations, and they then grew and animated into the appropriate animals (of a CR appropriate for the spell, of course).

According to the spell,

> Each beast is also considered fey, and it disappears when it drops to 0 hit points or when the spell ends.

Your statues would thus be destroyed after the spell ended or the animal was reduced to 0 HP.

You would need to discuss with your DM whether or not this will be allowed, but as this is a change to the spell's flavor rather than mechanics, for the most part, they may be willing to accommodate you.

Comment: Related on [How do you determine which beast appears during conjure animals?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71346/how-do-you-determine-which-beast-appears-during-conjure-animals) This may also impact the DMs decision.

Comment: I like this idea; might be worth making each beast also a construct-type creature rather than also a fey-type creature to better fit the "animated objects" theme, but that depends on how far their DM is willing to go for the sake of reflavouring, since anti-fey spells and effects would no longer work, etc...

Comment: @NathanS  - Yeah, that's moving from flavor change to mechanical change and creating a homebrew spell.

Comment: OP clarified in a comment that they are playing with adventurer's league rules. I'm pretty sure that the fluff won't matter, but the concern of what beasts are conjured becomes more of an issue.

Comment: OP has updated what they want their carvings to do, you may want to adjust your answer.

Comment: I got to use this in our last session, and it worked very nicely combined with Wild Shape. I threw down two carved wolves, cast Conjure Animals, then transformed into a Dire Wolf on my bonus action, and led them into battle.

Answer (score 6):

## There is no druid spell that is able to do that below 5th level

Unfortunately what you want to do is simply not a part of any druid spell lower than 5th level. In fact, *[animate objects](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animate-objects)* is also not on the druid spell list which means you aren't able to even cast that.

If there was something specific you wanted the tiny creatures   to do you could possibly reflavor other spells to have them enacting that effect, but otherwise you don't really have any options as a druid.

#### *[Tiny servant](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/tiny-servant)* if you can somehow get access to wizard spells

If you were a wizard or could get access to the 3rd-level wizard spell *tiny servant* you might be able to get some semblance of what you want, but there is no obvious or easy way to do that (and  you can't even cast 3rd level spells yet).

Comment: OP has updated what they want their carvings to do, you may want to adjust your answer.